# Using ARM DS-5 with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, arm, cortex-m, ds-5

I am trying to do some embedded programming for an online course.  The IDE I had to use does not have a Linux version, so I am planning to use the ARM DS-5.  It says it can be used with eclipse but I cannot figure out how to get them to work.  I have Ubuntu 14.04. I read somewhere that the ARM-DS-5 wouldn't work with anything newer than indigo but that was from 2012 and am not sure how accurate that is now.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Assuming this is the Community Edition, why not just get the version [prepackaged with Eclipse](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/getting-started/) instead of the [separate plugin](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/getting-started-update-site/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the use-case, you can pick one the three DS-5 variants.

- **Community Edition**

  - Free to use.
  - Allows Linux library/app debug using GNU tools.
  - Comes in two flavors - [Eclipse Plugin](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/getting-started-update-site/) and [Full Fledged IDE](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-community-edition/getting-started/).
- **Professional Edition**

  - 30 days free evaluation.
  - Allows bare-metal (no OS) and Linux kernel and app debug.
  - Comes with ARM compiler, debugger along with GNU tools.
  - Comes with `FVP`, ARM's virtual hardware, allowing development without real hardware.
- [**Ultimate edition**](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5-ultimate-edition/)

  - Everything in the Professional edition plus support for `ARMv8`, the ARM's architecture with 64-bit support.

You can visit [here](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/compare-ds-5-editions/) to see more detailed difference between various editions.

Note there is only one DS-5 IDE installer, which is available for download [here](http://ds.arm.com/ds-5/downloads). The variant is decided based on type of license chosen. So if you download DS-5 Ultimate for 30-day eval, it can converted to Community edition by changing the license at the end of eval period.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded something else from the da.arm.com site thinking it was the complete IDE packaged with Eclipse.

Comment: @chamburger, I am curious to know which edition did you end up using?

Comment: I am not sure as i am not home but I think it was the version here http://ds.arm.com/downloads/

Comment: then I followed the instruction from here http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0478-/Bhcccdab.html section "3.2 Installing DS-5"  this is the pdf I used http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0478v/DUI0478V_getting_started_guide.pdf  It showed up as an installed app on my computer as "Eclipse for ARM DS-5" but when I clicked it, it never ran, gonne try the community edition when I get home.

Comment: @chamburger It may be worthwhile to see http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/tutorials/, especially http://ds.arm.com/developer-resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-arm-ds-5-development-studio/